# Corda: How to use the AndComposition with a VaultCustomQueryCriteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, corda

I use a RPC client (Java Spring Boot application) to connect to a Corda 4.6 node.

I want to run a custom vault query with the following query criteria:

```java
QueryCriteria stateStatusCriteria = new VaultQueryCriteria(StateStatus.ALL);
QueryCriteria myFieldCriteria = new VaultCustomQueryCriteria(
  Builder.equal(getField("myField", PersistentMyState.class), myValue)
);
return stateStatusCriteria.and(myFieldCriteria);
// Also tried: return myFieldCriteria.and(stateStatusCriteria);
```

This is very similar to the example from the [Corda documentation](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.6/api-vault-query.html#custom-queries-in-java).

However, I just retrieve `UNCONSUMED` states. What could go wrong here?

The following snippet is working, but I need an `AndComposition` since I want to add more custom criteria later:

```java
QueryCriteria myFieldCriteria = new VaultCustomQueryCriteria(
  Builder.equal(getField("myField", PersistentMyState.class), myValue), 
  StateStatus.ALL
);
return myFieldCriteria ;
```

Moreover, any hints how to activate Hibernate logging in Corda are appreciated. I am using custom CorDapps in a  `corda/corda-zulu-java1.8-4.6:RELEASE` image running in a Kubernetes cluster with a PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** UPDATE **

The `VaultCustomQueryCriteria` by default set the `stateStatus = UNCONSUMED` in [its constructor](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/acde7cc3642745b75572323ed8e4bc5fe77d38eb/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/node/services/vault/QueryCriteria.kt#L579):

```
    data class VaultCustomQueryCriteria<L : StatePersistable>(
        val expression: CriteriaExpression<L, Boolean>,
        override val status: Vault.StateStatus = Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED,
        override val contractStateTypes: Set<Class<out ContractState>>? = null,
        override val relevancyStatus: Vault.RelevancyStatus = Vault.RelevancyStatus.ALL)
```

So, if you do not pass the StateStatus, the query will always return the `UNCONSUMED` states and the `and()` predicative of Hibernate will not work, in case you have also `CONSUMED` states.
There is also [this](https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/5328) interesting issue on github with a similar case.
So basically your first snippet should be like this:

```
QueryCriteria stateStatusCriteria = new VaultQueryCriteria(StateStatus.ALL);
QueryCriteria myFieldCriteria = new VaultCustomQueryCriteria(
Builder.equal(getField("myField", PersistentMyState.class), myValue), StateStatus.ALL);
return stateStatusCriteria.and(myFieldCriteria);
```

To activate the Hibernate logger, you have to update the `log4j.xml` file in your cordapp to add the Hibernate configuration, probably something like this:

```
<Configuration monitorInterval="60">
<Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">PropertiesConfiguration</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console-Appender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>
                [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
            </pattern>>
        </PatternLayout>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Comment: This is not clear to me. For `MyState` I have some `UNCONSUMED` and some `CONSUMED` and I want to query `ALL` of them. With the first snippet I retrieve just the `UNCONSUMED` while the second snippet returns `ALL` (but does not scale well).

Comment: In the Corda source they also [set the StateStatus to `ALL`](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/HEAD/node/src/test/java/net/corda/node/services/vault/VaultQueryJavaTests.java#L274), but only retrieve 2 `UNCONSUMED` states. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Max I updated my answer. You need to pass the StateStatus.CONSUMED/ALL to the VaultQueryCustomCriteria constructor otherwise it will set it to UNCONSUMED by default. Please check and accept the answer if it you think it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be a bug as you have to set the state status in each `VaultCustomQueryCriteria` but it is only used once during query execution. It is described in the bug report you mentioned. Thanks for the update!

Comment: It is not a bug, right? It working as designed.